# Associate couples between 2 tables with SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

The question is easy, answer is not (for me).

I have 2 identical tables composed of 2 columns : ID and value. I have to find all couples sharing the same value. So when a record is used in a couple, it can't be reused in another couple.

For example, with this two tables :

```
CREATE TABLE [Tab1]([ID1] [int], [Val] [int]) 
CREATE TABLE [Tab2]([ID2] [int], [Val] [int])
INSERT [Tab1] ([ID1], [Val]) VALUES (1, 10)
INSERT [Tab1] ([ID1], [Val]) VALUES (2, 20)
INSERT [Tab1] ([ID1], [Val]) VALUES (3, 20)
INSERT [Tab1] ([ID1], [Val]) VALUES (4, 50)
INSERT [Tab1] ([ID1], [Val]) VALUES (5, 100)
INSERT [Tab2] ([ID2], [Val]) VALUES (1, 20)
INSERT [Tab2] ([ID2], [Val]) VALUES (2, 10)
INSERT [Tab2] ([ID2], [Val]) VALUES (3, 50)
INSERT [Tab2] ([ID2], [Val]) VALUES (4, 30)
INSERT [Tab2] ([ID2], [Val]) VALUES (5, 20)
GO
```

a good answer would be (there are several solutions, but one is enough) :

```
ID1  ID2    Val
---  ----   ---
2    1      20
1    2      10
4    3      50
3    5      20
```

I'm looking for a query to find this result. I use SQL Server 2005 but I can use SQL Server 2008 if it's needed.

Comment: What do you mean by "couples"?  If I understand, shouldn't id1 of 4 = id2 of 3, etc?

Comment: I think a couple is a pair consisting of ID and value.

Comment: A couple is an ID in each table that have the same value. For example, line 2 (ID1=2)  from tab1 with line 1 (ID2=1) from tab2 is a couple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work on SQL Server 2008, but I'm not sure it will on 2005.

```
SELECT t1.Val, ID1, ID2 FROM
(SELECT Val, ID1, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Val ORDER BY ID1) rank FROM Tab1) t1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT Val, ID2, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Val ORDER BY ID2) rank FROM Tab2) t2
ON t1.Val = t2.Val AND t1.rank = t2.rank
```

The trick here is to rank the ID's in each table by their ID and partition by the Val. Than joining by rank only returns valid results.

And here's an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f4724/25)